# Any ideas/assistance how to get "npm start " working

Tags: node.js, npm

I get the following error when running `npm start`. How can I resolve this?

```
Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'E:\reactjs-example\project2\'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm''
TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
    at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:97:27)
    at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
    at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:225:22)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:263:24
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:81:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:80:13
    at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:171:20)
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:97
  var doExit = npm.config.loaded ? npm.config.get('_exit') : true
```

Comment: Please provide your actual code/ package.json so that others can identify what is actually triggering this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Open the " C:\Users\yourUserName" then you will see a file named `.npmrc`, open it in Notepad, as follows:

[image]

Then change or amend the text as follows:

```
= D prefix: \ nodejs \ node_global
Cache = D: \ nodejs \ node_cache
```

When this is done, you can reopen your command line and run your npm command again. Hope this works for you like a magic.

**NOTE:** Make sure you replace your Drive Alphabet appropriately.

Please don't forget to give this post a **Thumb-Up**